# SQL injection without the use of union and select

Tags: sql-injection

I was wondering if there is a way to use SELECT and UNION keywords without being caught by a algorithm (see below) that filters these keywords out.

```
 $filter = array('UNION', 'SELECT');

    // Remove all banned characters
    foreach ($filter as $banned) {
        if (strpos($_GET['q'], $banned) !== false) die("Hacker detected"); 
        if (strpos($_GET['q'], strtolower($banned)) !== false) die("Hacker detected"); 
    }
```

Comment: Which language or SGBD are you using? You forget to tell. Is this PHP?

Answer (score 1):

This filter searches for `UNION`, `SELECT`, `union`, and `select`. So `UnIoN` or `SeLeCt` will pass the filter.

Comment: I wonder if  ```UNION+``` bypasses the check too

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to point out that you should uppercase the query because you're only comparing upper and lower case, and a mixed case input like `UnIoN` would not be detected. So instead of two strpos(), I'd use a single one with `strtoupper($_GET['q'])`.

There are many ways to do SQL injection without using the keywords SELECT or UNION. There's a long article I wrote on different ways to do SQL injection: http://bluecoreresearch.com/blog/sql-injection/ (along with how to protect against it).

Here are a few example from this article that would bypass your code:

- The classic example for SQL injection is actually `0 OR 1=1` (using the OR keyword)
- If talking to SQL Server, you could inject a complete SQL, like `0; CREATE LOGIN hacker WITH PASSWORD = 'password'`
- If your SQL is something like `select .. from .. where id = $id`, sending the input "id" instead of a number would generate this SQL `select .. from .. where id = id` and return all the rows.

There's a lot of ways to manipulate the SQL construct and make it do something that was not intended. If you want to protect against SQL injection, I suggest you study them more carefully. The above article I wrote is one place to read, and another is https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection (make sure you also follow all their links at the bottom).

The only way to really solve SQL injection is by using bind variables in the code. I know it's a hassle to change all the code but in your above example you seem to only be protecting a single query. So a much better solution would be to change the query to use a bind variable.

If you have to protect a lot of code and using bind variables (or another best practices mentioned in that article) is not a viable option, you'll have to use a WAF and/or database auditing.